# My bank did not withdraw the funds for a check I wrote

Tags: banking

My bank didn't withdraw funds for a rent check I wrote over 4 months ago. However, my apt. manager received those funds. What do I do?

Comment: Contact the bank.

Comment: Note that you do not ‘own’ the extra money, until at least a year has passed. Do not spend it; be prepared to pay it if asked. It’s not your duty to keep running after someone and tell him he made an error; but it’s not yours just because he did.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you've got something in writing that your landlord has received rent. Second, put something in writing to the bank seeking an explanation why your account was not debited the amount in question. Third, wait for written acknowledgement from your bank before letting your balance dip below the amount in question. Fourth, if unsatisfied by anything above, consider a bank upgrade.

What happened? Probably an error by the bank. Or maybe a kind of race condition as tenant deposited funds to the account to cover the check while the landlord was presenting the check to the bank. I've had a check from a tenant go through then get called back for non-sufficient funds and then I had to rerun the check.

Comment: The issue could be with the landlords bank. Or the management company made a mistake. If the check never made it to the tenant's bank, they wouldn't even know to pull the funds from the account.